# Push notification from Worker Service to mobile app

Tags: asp.net-core

I am new to ASP.NET Core and have some questions.
My system which has a worker service, a grpc service, a web API and mobile and web clients as below architecture. The system is monitoring sensor temperature, if temperature is out of threshold, the client will receive a push notification of warning. So the worker service is for monitoring temperature. The grpc service is for turning on a light.

1. Is my system is a microservice architecture system? (I'm not clearly)
2. How should I push notification to clients (mobile app) when temperature is out of threshold? I use Firebase Cloud Messaging to push notification but where should I do send request to FCM? Worker service send request to FCM directly or worker send request to web API and web API send request to FCM?
3. If the temperature is out of threshold I will send notification to clients but I think I send once for per warning. If the user receive notification and next time if temperature is out of threshold again I will send other notification. How can I implement this?
4. I want to log (save) temperature to database every 5 minutes for history view. And where should I do implement database connection? worker service directly write to database or worker service send temperature data to web api and web api write to database?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to think of your pipeline, the way you receive your data and how you store it.After that you can hook different clients (services) to act upon received values , derived values , logging etc:

- The worker service is the producer it should provide data , and you can link to it either pull based (you pull data from it) or push based , it provides a callback whenever a new measurement is generated.
- You need a gateway to consume from that worker and maybe perform some preprocessing logic to curate your data , (the entry point of the data in your system).
- From this gateway you can decide what to do with your data.You can send it to multiple consumers and / or to some storage device.
- Your consumers could be as simple as some methods applied on each value received or as complex as entire external systems. You can go as deep as you like.

[image]

In the above picture , your gateway could be a console app that runs a loop reading from a socket  or a web api that responds to http requests.
In either case based upon the readings it receives in can then send the records to a database or to a `FCM` external system , or a logging one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will search more about your architecture suggestion.

Comment: It would be very useful if you could provide more information regarding the `Worker Service` and how external systems can fetch data from it ( what protocol it uses , the throughput etc ).Once that is clear you can tailor the gateway and everything that uses the derived data around the producer.